# How to send an email using Gmail from GCF?

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-run, service-accounts

I have a Cloud function set up to run with service account with credentials provided by ADC. I would like to send emails from a Gmail account. Ideally the sender should be the service account, but as I've [read](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2322#issuecomment-692908531) this is not possible. I'm the project's owner and if I could send emails from my account that would be ok too.

The proposed solution is domain-wide delegation which seems to have it's own [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202767/gae-attributeerror-credentials-object-has-no-attribute-with-subject) (though GCE and GAE are mentioned, but not Cloud run), and I'm not even sure it applies to me, since I don't use Workspace or Cloud Identity.

What are my options here, because I don't see any?